# Calling fopen in gdb

Tags: gdb, reverse-engineering, fopen, elf

I'm reversing a compiled program (written in C) and this one opens a file (which I don't have permission to read) like this:

```
fopen("/home/user00/.pass", 'r')
```

then it checks the return:

```
   ...
   0x4008a8 <main+148>: call   0x400700 <fopen@plt>
   0x4008ad <main+153>: mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],rax
=> 0x4008b1 <main+157>: cmp    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x0
   0x4008b6 <main+162>: jne    0x4008e6 <main+210>
   0x4008dc <main+200>: mov    edi,0x1
   0x4008e1 <main+205>: call   0x400710 <exit@plt>
   ...
```

So if the file doesn't open the program exits.

I obviously can trick this, setting `$rax=1`, but then the program will try to read the file and it receives a segfault.
So I thought I can:

```
gdb call fopen("/a/file/I/can/read", 'r')
```

And continue my reverse work, but sadly the program receives a different segfault when I execute this command.

So I wonder, is it possible in some way (by allocating or whatever) to call `fopen` ?
I already searched answers on the internet without success.

This program is part of my school's Security ISO CTF challenge.

Thanks!

Comment: The program is storing the result of fopen in `QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8]` and is presumably using that value later on (we can't see that code). If you call fopen on your own, you should store its return value in that same place.

Comment: The 2nd argument to fopen is a NUL-terminated string rather than a char.

Comment: This is exactly what I am looking for, but how can I call fopen and store the return address?

Comment: 'Cause, right now I am faking the return address. Actually `fopen` will return zero (fail). And later the code will try to read from the file, so obviously it will segfault. But if I can `call fopen(...)` correctly I can fake the all thing correctly and proceed reversing.

Comment: So what you want to do is make the program read from your FILE* that your fopen returned rather than the null FILE* that its own fopen returned. Think how you would make that happen. Gdb's `set` command lets you write into any variable in the program. Write your own small C program that acts like your target program and try things out.

Comment: Why not just stop the program before it calls `fopen` and modify the pathname argument so that it refers to a file that can be successfully opened?

Comment: @ottomeister that's also an idea!

Comment: @MarkPlotnick rewriting the program in C is really difficult, especially that I don't know what the code does next (after `fopen()`)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> sadly the program receives a different segfault when I execute this command.

That's because you have a bug in your command. It should be:

```
(gdb) call fopen("/a/file/I/can/read", "r")
```

(Unlike in Python, the kind of quotes you use in `C` matters.)